# Hidden unicode characters when moving data from one server to another (MSSQL13) - maybe collation issue?

Tags: sql-server, unicode

When moving data (a char(18) field) from one MSSQL13 to another MSSQL13 I lose "hidden" unicode characters.

Src is Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS.

Tgt is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Example:
The char(18) filed L_KEY in the source table is shown as `'9060001429   00099'` when I choose "Results to Text".

When I choose "Results to Grid" it is shown as `'9060001429'`

When I look at the concrete example and its individual characters and their unicode number, I get this:

```
Pos   UnicodeChar  UnicodeValue
---   -----------  ------------
1     9            57
2     0            48
3     6            54
4     0            48
5     0            48
6     0            48
7     1            49
8     4            52
9     2            50
10    9            57
11                  0
12                  0
13                  0
14    0            48
15    0            48
16    0            48
17    9            57
18    9            57
```

So it seems positions 11,12, and 13 hold a null value.

When I select data into a table on the same server with the same collation; I get the same results.

When I select data into a table on a different server with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS I lose positions 11-18 in the above example.

I've tried to create a table in the target database with a column with the same collation as the source column and tried to move data using SSIS import/export wizard.

If I use an explicit conversion in my query in SSIS import/export wizrad 
(    convert(nvarchar(18),L_KEY)     ) I can see the "missing" characters in the SSIS preview window. Nevertheless, when data is inserted into the target table, the characters are gone.

Please help

NB. I cannot use openrowset or linked servers.

Comment: `a char(18) field` that's your problem. That's a single-codepage type. Use `nchar(13)` instead to store strings as Unicode and avoid all conversion issues. Otherwise characters that can't be translated to the destination codepage will be lost. The codepages are controlled by the collation indeed.

Comment: What does `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), L_KEY)` give you? If you have actual NUL characters in your string, you do have a rather serious problem, because many T-SQL functions and clients do not appreciate this one bit -- traditionally NUL is the string terminator character in C and languages like it. Rather than copying these as-is, you should aim to get rid of them altogether. You can do this by using the `Latin1_General_BIN` collation, which does respect NUL (up to a point) and can be used to replace it.

Comment: PS there are no hidden Unicode characters in this case. `char` isn't a Unicode type. It's a simple conversion error between incompatible codepages.

Comment: CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), L_KEY) gives me:
`0x393036303030313432390000003030303939`

Comment: Yep, those are true-blue NULs. Kill them with fire -- `REPLACE(L_KEY COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, CHAR(0), ' ') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` should do. If you actually wanted to copy them whole, I don't know if you can even do that with SSIS -- likely only by bouncing everything through a binary type to avoid any and all string processing. (Considering a move to Unicode types is still a good idea to avoid any possible conversion issues between the Danish/Norwegian code page and Latin-1 -- otherwise you can still get corrupted characters. It's a separate issue, but still.)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, both of you!

`REPLACE(L_KEY COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, CHAR(0), ' ') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` did the job.

Thanks!!